# Postman - How to send large JSON body?

Tags: postman

I am trying to do a POST request using Postman with a very large body. Only one JSON field is very large, I wonder if I could load that field from a file in Postman?

```
{
  "field1": {
    "field1.1" : ...
    ...
  }
  "field2": {
    "LARGE FIELD": "<<Too large string to paste into this Raw JSON>>"
  }
}
```

Is there any best-practice to deal with a very large body in Postman?

Comment: have you tried passing it through a data file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use csv file for upload as

  `LARGEFIELD, <<Too large string>>`
- Now in 'Pre-request script' use parametrization as below:

  ```
  var LARGE_FIELD= pm.iterationData.get("LARGEFIELD");

  pm.environment.set("envLARGE_FIELD", LARGE_FIELD);
  ```
- now use the above env . parameter directly into body as below:

  ```
  {
      "field1": {
          "field1.1" : ...
          ...
      }
      "field2": {
          "LARGE FIELD": {{envLARGE_FIELD}}
      }
  }
  ```
- while running collection, load this csv file
- postman runtime will pick the data and assign it to request body